# testing functions with unexpected output

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a program written to compute derivatives of expressions in list form so `4x^3` is represented as `(* 4 (expt x 3))` and I am writing a test-suite to print out results. I have a function `runtest` that takes an expression and computes the derivative with respect to `x` and returns the results

```
(define (runtest test)
  (display "diff x ")(display test)(display " => ")(display (diff 'x test)))
```

so that the results display `diff x expression => result`

I have the following defined as tests:

```
(define test1 '4)
(define test2 '(* 2 x))
(define test3 '(* 2 y))
(define test4 '(+ x (* x x)))
(define test5 '(expt x 4))
```

and then I put all of the tests in a list so I could map over the list and return the results:

```
(define test-suite (list test1 test2 test3 test4 test5))
```

and when I run `(map runtest test-suite)` instead of returning each separately I get a long list with no line breaks when instead I want:

```
diff x 4 => 0
diff x '(* 2 x) => '(+ (* 0 x) (* 2 1))
diff x '(* 2 y) => '(+ (* 0 y) (* 2 0))
diff x '(+ x (* x x)) => '(+ 1 (* 2 x))
diff x '(expt x 4) => '(* 4 (expt x 3))
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `newline`:

```
(define (runtest test)
  (display "diff x ")
  (display test)
  (display " => ")
  (display (diff 'x test))
  (newline))
```

BTW, there's seldom a good reason to call `display` on anything but a string; I would recommend using `write` for `test` and `(diff 'x test)`.

A more idiomatic way to write it in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) is this:

```
(define (runtest test)
  (printf "diff x ~s => ~s\n" test (diff 'x test)))
```

or, in any Scheme with [SRFI-28](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-28/srfi-28.html), this:

```
(define (runtest test)
  (display (format "diff x ~s => ~s~%" test (diff 'x test)))
```